# Which php framework is good for shared hosting?

Tags: php, frameworks, hosting, shared

I'm trying to use a PHP framework, but I don't have confidence with Composer and terminal commands. I would like to download a framework and upload it on my shared hosting and start to develop my application.
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: codeigniter is a good bet for beginners, assuming you understand mvc. http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-framework-2015-sitepoint-survey-results/

Comment: Yes, I understand mvc, I used cakephp when I could download it. But now with all the dependency  is too much difficoult. I wanted to create my own framework using some tutorial, but at the end it is a bad idea. 'l try codeigniter. But I saw that i could also download Zend Framework 2.4.9 Full. Do you suggest it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodeIgniter https://codeigniter.com is a powerful PHP framework with a very small footprint

1.Unzip the package.

2.Upload the CodeIgniter folders and files to your server. Normally the index.php file will be at your root.

3.Open the application/config/config.php file with a text editor and set your base URL. If you intend to use encryption or sessions, set your encryption key.

4.If you intend to use a database, open the application/config/database.php file with a text editor and set your database settings.

If you wish to increase security by hiding the location of your CodeIgniter files you can rename the system and application folders to something more private. If you do rename them, you must open your main index.php file and set the $system_path and $application_folder variables at the top of the file with the new name you’ve chosen.

For the best security, both the system and any application folders should be placed above web root so that they are not directly accessible via a browser. By default, .htaccess files are included in each folder to help prevent direct access, but it is best to remove them from public access entirely in case the web server configuration changes or doesn’t abide by the .htaccess.

If you would like to keep your views public it is also possible to move the views folder out of your application folder.

After moving them, open your main index.php file and set the $system_path, $application_folder and $view_folder variables, preferably with a full path, e.g. ‘/www/MyUser/system’.

One additional measure to take in production environments is to disable PHP error reporting and any other development-only functionality. In CodeIgniter, this can be done by setting the ENVIRONMENT constant, which is more fully described on the security page.

That’s it!

you've got yourself a powerful MVC framework wherever you go. it is also very popular.

Comment: As suggested from @Pamblam and you I just downloaded it and it seems the real thing I needed! Thank you all.

Comment: Do subdomains keep working? I've got a subdomain, and it should still be working serperately.

Comment: @Refilon yes no problem about that !

Answer (score 7):

As posted above (or below?), I'd highly suggest Laravel. It currently is the most powerful, complete and versatile framework. Requires less code than most framework to achieve something.

You don't really have to know composer, since the commands to install the packages are given to you in a copy-paste version. All packages installation methods are neatly documented for each package.

You will need to tweak the "public" directory so it points instead to the public_html folder via a symlink.

A simple symlink will do. Add this to the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

If you don't have cPanel shell access simply use the cron function to make the symlink for you.

Comment: I upvoted for the cron trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much use almost all the frameworks including Symfony2, Laravel, Codeigniter or CakePHP and etc. However if you have never used a framework I'd suggest you to use Laravel. Because Laravel has a great community as well as with laracasts.com(which has great screencasts about PHP, Laravel and even JS).

If you have an experience with a framework, then I'd suggest you to try out Symfony2. It is one of the best frameworks for PHP. Also Symfony is becoming the industry standard. There are many great projects that are built top of Symfony components including;

- Drupal
- Laravel(yes laravel uses some of Symfony's components)
- Joomla
- Magento
- Codeception and etc.

Many high profile companies are looking for Symfony developers. So there are many great opportunities at great companies if you are a Symfony developer.

Comment: But mind you that when researching the hosting options for laravel almost all developers tell you: "don't do laravel on shared hosting". That being said, if your shared hosting comes with terminal (ssh) access, and you're comfortable with the linux command line, and know proper software engineering (MVC) then it should be no problem. I run Laravel on shared hosting and it's running fine, though the setup (mainly paths) did bring me some headaches. Also you should check the php version allowed by the hosting company, since Laravel loves the newest versions. For Laravel 5.6 you need php 7.1.3!